# No SDL2 window shown when compile and run

Tags: c, sdl-2

I use DevC++ on Windowss 10 but my problem is that I followed some tutorials about SDL2 in C but when I write the program they give, it compiles well, however I can't see my window.
The problem may come from the "searched directories " as I had issues to install SDL2 on DevC++

```
// Code :

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SDL_Window *ecran = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

ecran = SDL_CreateWindow("DBZ", 0, 0, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(ecran, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

SDL_Delay(30000);
SDL_Quit();


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Compiling project changes...

- Project Filename: C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\programmes\SDL\Premier essai\Projet1.dev
- Compiler Name: TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

### Building makefile...

- Filename: C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\programmes\SDL\Premier essai\Makefile.win

### Processing makefile...

- Makefile Processor: C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\mingw32-make.exe
- Command: mingw32-make.exe -f "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\programmes\SDL\Premier essai\Makefile.win" all

mingw32-make.exe: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

### Compilation results...

- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0
- Output Filename: C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\programmes\SDL\Premier essai\Projet1.exe
- Output Size: 298,20703125 KiB
- Compilation Time: 0,22s

Comment: Check for return value of SDL_Init?

Comment: Check all of the return values.

Comment: Yes i ve tried to write in stderr but i cannot find it

Comment: I created a file* "err.txt", but nothing written

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your window just creates and immediately closing?. Try replace your `SDL_Delay` with:

```
bool quit = false;
mainEvent = new SDL_Event();

while (!quit && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT) {
    SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows; no issues with compilation, but instant exit on run. In my case, I was linking using the [x86](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.22-win32-x86.zip) rather than [x64](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.22-win32-x64.zip) binary when attempting to use a 64 bit build rather than a 32 bit build.

To reproduce the problem, I had just adjusted the development library paths, updating them to

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -I..\SDL2-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 
LFLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -L..\SDL2-2.0.14\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
```

from `-I..\SDL2-2.0.14\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2`, but hadn't yet replaced the .dll files. After grabbing the x64 binary from the site above, all was well.